# Как сымитировать печать текста в ВК на python'е?

Tags: python, вконтакте

Чтобы вот так отображалось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делать такое нужно без использования инструментов для автоматизации действий браузера, а-ля selenium

Возможно есть какой-то метод api... Но я почему-то его так и не нашел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Плохо искал.

[messages.setActivity](https://vk.com/dev/messages.setActivity)

> После успешного выполнения возвращает 1. 
>   Текст «N набирает сообщение...» отображается в течение 10 секунд после вызова метода, либо до момента отправки сообщения.